# how to do a basic animation

Tags: python, animation

I have some interesting satellite imagery that I would like to put together to show the spread of a fire. I have a python script that generates what files need to be animated based on user input but I have no idea how to take those files and animate them. I would preferably like to have the animation in AVI format and done completely through python and I have tried using numpy and matpoltlib but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good tool for this is [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). For example, it can create an animation movie from a directory containing properly named png or jpeg files. You can use Python to name the files like `pic0001.png, pic0002.png, pic0003.png`.

For example, put all your png files in the directory `pics` and create a movie with 10 frames per second and the codec `libx264`:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -i pics/%04d.png -c:v libx264 my_movie.mp4
```

Comment: only one problem all of my files are in .gz format and after decompressing them they are .dat files. i dont know how to convert them to jpegs or pngs

Comment: @D.Adams Just ask a new question explaining what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks a lot @mike muller ffmpeg is doing a great job

Comment: just one more thing. how do i specify the directory where my files are in ffmpeg